# how to use getLastError in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, getlasterror

1,How can i get the return value of my operations in monogd, by python ?i know getLastError can be used in javascript.

2,is there limit to set modifer?
if i use
    **collection.update({"notification":"yes"},{"$set":**{ **"idx":idx,"src_md5":src_md5,"src_size":src_size,"src_time":int(src_time)},"$addToSet":

{"server_list":host_name}})**
it didn't work.
but when i use
    **collection.update({"notification":"yes"},{"$set":**
**{"idx":idx,"src_md5":src_md5,"src_size":src_size},"$set":**
**{"src_time":int(src_time)},"$addToSet":{"server_list":host_name}})**
it worked.
 why?

Comment: this is clearly a rtfm question and clearly answered by the pymongo api documentation - downvote

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
last_error = db.runCommand({"getLastError":1})
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use write concern keyword arguments, to ensure that `getLastError` is called.  The various methods are described below:

- **safe**: Use getlasterror for each write operation?
- **j** or **journal**: Block until write operations have been commited to the journal. Ignored if the server is running without journaling.
  Implies safe=True.
- **w**: (integer or string) If this is a replica set write operations won’t return until they have been replicated to the specified number
  or tagged set of servers. Implies safe=True.

You can set these write concerns at different levels depending on your needs:

- The [Connection level](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html?highlight=getlasterror#pymongo.connection.Connection):
- The [Database level](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=lasterror#pymongo.database.Database.safe)
- The [Collection level](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=lasterror#pymongo.collection.Collection.safe)
- On [individual queries](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=kwargs#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert)

---

2) Your query looks fine heres a test:

```
db.test2.save({notification: 'yes'})
db.test2.update({"notification": "yes"}, {
    "$set": {"idx": 'a', "src_md5": 'b', "src_size": 'c', "src_time": 1}, 
    "$addToSet": {"server_list": 'stackoverflow'}
})
db.test2.find()


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5decf0631996582479878"),
    "idx" : "a",
    "notification" : "yes",
    "server_list" : [
        "stackoverflow"
    ],
    "src_md5" : "b",
    "src_size" : "c",
    "src_time" : 1
}
```